# labeling dynamically for different list of data frames

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to create a custom function to give labels to modified list of data frames. For example, I have a data frame like below.

```
data<-data.frame( Q1=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1),
                  Q2=c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),
                  Q3=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,1),
                  Q4=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  Q5=c(NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA),
                  Q6=c(1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1),
                  Q7=c(NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA),
                  Q8=c(NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA),
                  region=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,NA,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,NA,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,NA,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
)
```

Comment: it seems the beginning of your example `data` definition is lost

Comment: not clear what should your function take as a working data: in your example with `coalesce()`, you're modifying the dataframe (`data`), but in your `conv_fac()` call example you seem to be passing the list with `df` and `df2` dataframes.

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: again, it's not clear what input is expected for your function. Is it a list of 2 dataframes, and both of them will be processed the same way as `data` in your example? Are they supposed to be always named `ALL` and `other`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conv_fac <- function(
  dataset, # list containing input dataframes
  labels   # list of vectors; in each vector, first label is destination column and all the rest are sources
  ){
  for (i in seq_len(length(dataset))){
    this_df <- dataset[[i]]
    for (this_label in labels){
      col_target <- this_label[1]
      cols_source <- this_label[-1]
      vecs <- this_df[,cols_source]
      cat('\nProcessing dataframe #',i,': column ',col_target, ' from columns ', paste0(cols_source, collapse = ', '),  sep = '')      
      this_df[[col_target]] <- coalesce(!!!vecs) 
    }
    this_df -> dataset[[i]]
  }
  return(dataset)
}

# Usage:

ldat <- list("ALL" = df, "other" =df2) 
var1 <- c("Q9","Q8","Q4")
var2 <- c("Q7","Q6","Q5")

ldat2 <- conv_fac(dataset = ldat, labels = list(var1,var2))
```

Comment: so ldat can be a list of many data frames,  have alot of chunks that have to be labelled for n number of list of variables

Comment: yes the code I provided will work for all dataframes contained in `dataset` list input

Comment: for a scenario like list of factor and labels  col_name <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
label <- c("asman","shakti","nakul","ram")   i have created a function conv_frac <- function(dataset,colnames,collabels) {
  lapply(dataset, function(p) {
    
    p[colnames] <- Map(function(x, y) factor(x, labels = y), 
                       p[colnames], collabels)
    p
  })
}    and i applying like ldat1 <- conv_frac(dataset = ldat,colnames = col_name,collabels = label)   so can i have a simple solution like this so that in future i can modify easily.

Comment: this is little complex for me

Comment: well as I said it's not clear from your question what was needed.

Comment: well its just below kind of thing for ldat but through a function only because i have many variables to be labelled.
data$Q9<-coalesce(data$Q8, data$Q4)
data$Q7<-coalesce(data$Q6, data$Q5)

Comment: it's two separate tasks, I'm not sure which one you mean to wrap into your function. One task is to transform a given column to vector, with provided labels. Another one is to "fill" the column with values from other columns using `coalesce()`. The code I provided solves the second task.

Comment: yes both, if you suggest how i can improve my question...??

Comment: try to describe more clearly how your function will be called (with what arguments) and what part of the transformation should be done. For now I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: well then my function does what you requested - did you try running it?

Comment: yes but i didn't understant what is the requirement for this
cat('\nProcessing dataframe #',i,': column ',col_target, ' from columns ', paste0(cols_source, collapse = ', '),  sep = '')

Comment: This `cat()` command is added just for debugging purposes - to help you understand what happens. You can remove that line, it will not change the data.